# How can I enable autoplay (not initiated by user) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, autoplay

I have one page that launches another page, and the launched page does a series of scrapes and then plays an audio based on the results.

This stopped working today, maybe because of a Firefox update, but I need to be able to enable auto play as it is critical that the audio plays when the launched page loads.

Here is what my current JavaScript code looks like:

```
function playHighRiskStock(){
  var highRiskStock = new Audio('./wav/high-risk.wav');
  highRiskStock.play();
}
```

It is now giving me the error:  `NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

It did this all-of-a-sudden (i.e. it was working perfectly yesterday autoplaying with no problems).

How do I configure my browser to allow autoplay, even if not initiated by the user?

I have looked at this page:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide but it doesn't give any actual JavaScript code examples on setting auto play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error in Firefox.  The following fixed it for me.  Didn't need a reboot or to reload the browser.

1. Click the Hamburger (Options Menu).
2. Pick the Options menu.
3. In the search textbox, enter "Sound".
4. A "Block websites from automatically playing sound" option will appear.
5. Either uncheck that option or click the "Exceptions" button beside it.  In my case, I added an exception for https://app.pluralsight.com.  It works fine now.

Another option is to use Chrome.

Good luck.

Comment: Just to update @Dave's answer... for Firefox 91 go to Tools menu on the menu bar or by clicking the "hamburger" button, then select "Settings". On the left sidebar click on "Privacy & Security" and look for the "Permissions" block, there you will see the Autoplay text and a settings button on its right side. After clicking that button you will see a popup window with a "Default for all websites" dropdown list containing the type of permission to apply.